# Compatibility of Ubutu and Ryzen 3900

Tags: compatibility

I'm getting a new computer with Ryzen 3900 as processor and Gygabyte X570 UD as the motherboard. I'd like to install Ubuntu. I tried to check for the presence of any compatibility issues and so far I did not find any, but I m still not sure of that. Any advice or recommendation?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Phoronix Bench Marks

Phoronix Has done a number of bench marks featuring AMD Ryzen 9 3900X

Here is one with AMD Ryzen 9 3900X vs. Intel Core i9 9900K using Ubuntu 19.10:

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=3900x-9900k-400&num=1

More can be found here:

https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-0253814508491313:1305299758&ie=UTF-8&q=Ryzen+3900&sa=Search&ref=